# How to put gtk.DrawingArea into gtk.Layout

Tags: python, gtk, gdk

I have some gtk.DrawingArea with circle i painted on it, if i put DA right into the window - everything is ok, but if i put it into the gtk.Layout that i put into the same window - i could not see the DA. Help me please.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import random,math

class EggClockFace(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("expose_event", self.expose)

    def expose(self, widget, event):
        print 'expose'
        self.context = widget.window.cairo_create()

        # set a clip region for the expose event
        self.context.rectangle(event.area.x, event.area.y,
                           event.area.width, event.area.height)
        self.context.clip()

        self.draw(self.context)

        return False

    def draw(self, context):
        rect = self.get_allocation()
        x = rect.x + rect.width / 2
        y = rect.y + rect.height / 2

        radius = min(rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2) - 5

        # clock back
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * math.pi)
        context.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
        context.fill_preserve()
        context.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
        context.stroke()

        #context.restore()



class LayoutExample:
    def WindowDestroy(self, widget, *data):
        gtk.main_quit()
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Пример Layout")
        window.set_default_size(300, 300)
        window.connect("destroy", self.WindowDestroy)
        self.layout = gtk.Layout(None, None)
        self.layout.set_size(600, 600)

        bark=EggClockFace()
        #self.layout.put(bark, 0, 0)
        #window.add(self.layout)

        window.add(bark) #IF I COMMENT THIS LINE, AND UNCOMMENT PREVIOUS TWO - I CANT SEE THE CIRCLE
        window.show_all()

def main():
    # enter the main loop
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LayoutExample()
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set initial size for the drawing area (using [set_size_request](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-size-request)). Try adding `self.set_size_request(300, 300)` in `__init__` and run the application.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That is the allocation scheme, unless request size of the widgets will be as much as needed. As drawing area doesnt containing anything as such nothing is allocated by default